# SIMPLE LIST ITEM CHECKED

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I am new to Android. I have a simple_list_item_checked list in my application which gives a list of time(clock time). The user selects a time and an alarm will be triggered at that particular time with a dialog box to cancel or snooze the alarm.I am able to store the checked item in this list when the activity is in onPause state. But when the user quits the application and starts a fresh one, I wanted to retain the checked state of the items which the user has already selected when he was using the app last time. Please help me with the concept. Would be great if you include some codes in your answer. If your answer is shared preference, please help me with some codes as in where should I set my preference and where should I get my preference. I tried searching over the internet for various tutorials but all give me only with the checkbox entity. But here I have don't have a separate checkbox and a list. Things viz. the string item and checkbox , are merged together for which I am seeking my answer for. This is the last part of the app that is pending with me. Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you select time from list(OnItemClickListener) at that time you need to store time with the userId and get that value at Oncreate of Activity which has the list of time.

**testApp.Activity**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(NewsListActivity.this);
String selectedTimeposition = sharedPreferences.getString(userId);
ListView lvNews = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvNews);
lvNews.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
            String selectedItemposition = yourarray.get(position);
            sharedPreferences.edit.putString(userId,
        selectedItemposition).commit;

        }

    });

 lvNews.setSelection(selectedTimeposition);
```

userId should be string

try this may be it helps you.

Comment: But I have no item on click listener set up in my project . Pls help me with some other answers if possible. So nice of you to reply on this. Thanks in advance